# Can you chain multiple whereEqualTo operations in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from Firestore by applying multiple **whereEqualTo** options. Firestore asked me to create a compounding index for this query and I created one. But still, i am getting no result.
What I am doing wrong?

```
 getCollection()
                .whereEqualTo(RxFeedBase.Key_FeedIsPublished, false)
                .whereEqualTo(RxFeedBase.Key_FeedType, RxEnumFeedEntry.EntryType.Quiz.ordinal())
                .orderBy(RxEntityNewsCategory.Key_WelcomeDate, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(activity, successListener)
                .addOnFailureListener(activity,failureListener);
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is the index that was linked from the error message? I'd expect the order of the fields to be: `newsWelcomeData (desc), feedIsPublished (asc), feedType (asc)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I got a link in Exception and created this index using that link

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen found the error. thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Sure thing. What was the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i was using the wrong name (RxEntityNewsCategory.Key_WelcomeDate) in the order by field wight one was (RxFeedBase.Key_FeedWelcomeDate)

Comment: Ouch, that's an easy one to miss - and a hard one for us to spot with constants involved. Glad you caught it.    I'm voting to close this as a typo.